# Geometry errors when importing shapefile with shp2pgsql PostGIS

Tags: postgis, gdal

I'm trying to import the [Census State Boundaries](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2019/shp/cb_2019_us_state_500k.zip) from the [census data site](https://www.census.gov/geographies/mapping-files/time-series/geo/cartographic-boundary.html) although I get errors in the `geom` data every time I import in the same rows.

I've tried `shp2pgsql` and `ogr2ogr`

```
shp2pgsql -I -d -e /Users/cj/Projects/geospacial_data/cb_2019_us_state_500k/cb_2019_us_state_500k.shp public.state | psql -h localhost -d my_db -U cj
```

and this

```
ogr2ogr -f "ESRI Shapefile" /Users/cj/Projects/geospacial_data/cb_2019_us_state_500k/cb_2019_us_state_500k.shp PG:"host=localhost user=cj dbname=mydb" "state"
```

The errors show up here in the `geom` column (in the screenshot) showing the loaded size. Are these errors just part of the file? or am I doing something wrong? This seems to crop up when I do Counties and zip codes as well.

[image]

I'm running

- PostGIS 3.0.1 (homebrew)
- PostgreSQL 12.3 (homebrew)
- GDAL 2.4.4 (homebrew)
- MacOS 10.14.6

Comment: Have you tried validating the geometries *before* placing them in the database? That would seem to be the answer to your first question.

Comment: How do you verify the geometry? Is that a separate tool? I suppose I made the mistake of assuming that since it was from the census website the geometry would be correct

Comment: You can take a look at the ogr2ogr website https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html . It includes a command -makevalid which you can add as part of your conversion

Comment: try running `select * from table where not st_isvalid(geom)`

Answer (score 0):

1. Prefer `ogr2ogr` over `shp2pgsql` because the former has many built-in validations for the supported data sources and destinations.
2. The [Census State Boundary SHP dataset](https://www2.census.gov/geo/tiger/GENZ2019/shp/cb_2019_us_state_500k.zip) claimed to be of type **POLYGON** but contained at least one row of **MULTIPOLYGON** geometry.
3. Use the following command to import the Census State Boundary SHP dataset into PostgreSQL (assuming that you had priorly enabled the PostGIS extension on the target database):

   `ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=localhost user=cj dbname=mydb" -nln state -nlt multipolygon cb_2019_us_state_500k.shp`

Comment: Shapefile does not make a distinction between single-part and multi-part Polygon (or, for that matter, single-part and multi-part Polyline). State boundaries for all coastal states are guaranteed to be multipart, so it would be an error to assume that states is single-part.